# How do properties work in Object Oriented MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, matlab-class

I am trying to create a MATLAB class with a member variable that's being updated as a result of a method invocation, but when I try to change the property within the class it (apperently, from what I understood from MATLAB's memory management) creates a copy of the object and then modifies it, leaving the original object's property untouched.

```
classdef testprop  
    properties  
        numRequests=0;  
    end  
    methods  
        function Request(this, val)  
            disp(val);  
            this.numRequests=this.numRequests+1;  
        end  
    end  
end
```

.

```
>> a=testprop;
>> a.Request(9);
>> a.Request(5);  
>> a.numRequests  

ans = 0
```

Comment: edited my answer to take your edits into account.

Comment: ooh, ahh... I'm still using R2006b and I guess they finally made classes "real" in MATLAB (used to be a pain in the butt)

Answer (score 29):

#### Using a Value (Vanilla) Class

When using a value class you need to tell Matlab to store a modified copy of the object to save the changes in the property value.  So,

```
>> a=testprop
>> a.Request(5); % will NOT change the value of a.numRequests.
5

>> a.Request(5) 
5

>> a.numRequests
ans = 
       0

>> a=a.Request; % However, this will work but as you it makes a copy of variable, a.
5

>> a=a.Request; 
5

>> a.numRequests
ans =
       2
```

As [Kamran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209005/object-oriented-matlab-properties/673190#673190) notes, this requires changing the definition of function `Request` to be

```
function this = Request(this, val)`
```

#### Using a Handle Class

If you inherit from the handle class, that is

```
classdef testprop < handle
```

then you can write,

```
>> a.Request(5);
>> a.Request(5);
>> a.numRequests
ans = 
       2
```

Note that this changes the behavior of the objects, see [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) to learn the difference between a value class and a handle class.

Comment: Yes - this demonstrated the issue, although line 8 was meant to be  this.numRequests=this.numRequests+1;

Answer (score 7):

You have to remember that syntactically in Matlab, you're probably closer to C, than C++ or Java, at least with respect to objects.  So, of you want to change the "contents" of a value object (really just a special `struct`), you need to return the object from the function.

Azim was correct to point out that if you want [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) behavior (which, from your code, you seem to), you need to use a "handle" class.  Instances of classes that derive from Handle all point to a single instance, and operate only on it.

You can [read more about the differences between Value and Handle classes.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html)

Comment: Deriving from `handle` does not, by itself, make the Singleton pattern.

Comment: The link no longer points to what I think was intended.  [Here is an updated link.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html)

Answer (score 5):

I made the class **testprop** and tried to excute the code which Azim suggested but it did not work. When I executed the following command:

```
a=a.Request(1)
```

The following error was generated:

> ??? Error using ==> Request
>   Too many output arguments.

I think the problem is that we did not determine any output when declaring **Request** method. So we should change it to:

```
function this = Request(this, val)
```

and now:

```
>> a = testprop;
>> a = a.Request(1);        
>> a.numRequests

ans = 1
```

Comment: If "testprop" is to be written as a standard/vanilla class, you would need to return the object from "Request". If "testprop" is derived from the handle class, you shouldn't need to return anything. You would simply use the call "a.Request(1);".

Comment: yes you're right, but as in the question, Azim has supposed the difiniton of the testprop class is not derived from handle class. so he shoud have modified the method "Request".

Comment: @Kamran, just checked and you are correct. I  must have included an output argument for Request when I was testing the Vanilla case. Thanks for the clarification.