# changing class properties with its methods

Tags: matlab, methods, properties

I'd like to change my class properties with a method defined for that class:

```
classdef triangle<handle

properties
    a
    h         
end

methods

    function obj = triangle()
        obj;
    end

    function obj = setProps(obj, a, h)
        obj.a = a;
        obj.a = h;
    end

end

end
```

Calling:

```
t = triangle();
t.setProps(a, h);
```

It's not working at all - I get this error:

```
 The class 'handle' is not a super-class of class 'triangle', as required to invoke a super-class constructor or method.

 Error in triangle (line 13)
    function obj = triangle()
```

I'm using matlab 2012a. My code is based on this example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272618/how-to-modify-properties-of-a-matlab-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `clear` before doing this. It is possible that you've overwritten `handle` with something. Otherwise, this works for me on Matlab 2012a:

```
clear;

a = 'hello';
h = 1;

t = triangle();
t.setProps(a, h);
```