# Matlab Array which stores numbers of any base

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop

This is the first Matlab code I've ever written so it's probably pretty rough.

A friend is working in Matlab and mentioned that they wanted to have an array which could take and return numbers in any base. This is what I came up with, but it doesn't work.

```
classdef BaseArray
   properties
      Value
   end
   methods
      function obj = BaseArray(Elements, Base)
        Value = base2dec(Elements, Base)
      end
      function add (Obj, Element, Base)
        % This might need some sort of "void" return type
        Obj.Value = [Obj.Value base2dec(Element, Base)]
      end
      function get (Obj, Base)
        % How do I get this to actually return
        str2num(dec2base(Obj.Value, Base))
   end
end
```

When I try to call

```
a=BaseArray([011, 101, 110], 2)
```

From the same file (this is wrong?) I get an error saying that BaseArray is not defined.

I'd like the class to work like this:

```
a=BaseArray([2, 4, 8], 10)
a.Add(10, 3)
a.get(2)
% returns [10, 100, 1000, 11]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it working.  Let's go through a summary of the changes you need to get this fully working:

(1) You need to inherit from the `handle` class if you want your object to maintain its changes after you run through your methods.  This can be done by appending the following to your `classdef` definition:

```
classdef BaseArray < handle
```

Check out a related post on why this is so: [How to modify properties of a Matlab Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272618/how-to-modify-properties-of-a-matlab-object)

(2) `base2dec` requires a **string** representation of the number.  As such, you can't use an array of numbers or MATLAB is going to complain.  As such, when you create an object of type `BaseArray`, you need to do it like this:

```
a = BaseArray({'2', '4', '8'}, 10);
```

Take note that I declared a `cell` array of strings.  We can't throw this into a normal array, or else the strings will just concatenate with each other and it will form a single string of `248`, which is obviously not what we want.

(3) When you're adding in a number, when you created your initial object, your `Value` property will actually be a **column** of numbers due to the nature of `base2dec`.  As such, you need to concatenate the numbers **vertically** instead of horizontally.  As such, your add method needs to be:

```
  function add(obj, Element, Base)
    %//This might need some sort of "void" return type
    obj.Value = [obj.Value; base2dec(Element, Base)];
  end
```

Also, make sure you call `add` this way:

```
a.add('3', 10);
```

... not `a.add(10,3)` as you had it before.  You flipped the number and the base... you also need to ensure that `3` is a string.

(4) You missed an `end` statement at the end of the `get` method

(5) The `get` method is almost correct.   You just have to create an output variable, and assign the call from `str2num` to that variable.  As such:

```
  function val = get(obj, Base)
    %//How do I get this to actually return
    val = str2num(dec2base(obj.Value, Base));
  end
```

---

With all of this, this is what your final class definition looks like.  Make sure you save this to a file called `BaseArray.m`:

```
classdef BaseArray < handle
   properties
      Value;
   end
   methods
      function obj = BaseArray(Elements, Base)
        obj.Value = base2dec(Elements, Base);
      end
      function add(obj, Element, Base)    
        obj.Value = [obj.Value; base2dec(Element, Base)];
      end
      function val = get(obj, Base)
        val = str2num(dec2base(obj.Value, Base));
      end
   end
end
```

Going with your example, we thus have:

```
a = BaseArray({'2', '4', '8'}, 10);
a.add('3', 10);
b = a.get(2);
```

`b` gives us:

```
b =

      10
     100
    1000
      11
```

Comment: `{'2','4','8'} = arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x), [2,4,8], 'UniformOutput', false)`

Comment: @Yvon - Though that is certainly equivalent.... I like `{'2','4','8'}` better :).  Good observation though.

Comment: Yeah I see it now. With `[2,4,8]` you can only have decimal inputs. With strings you can take `{'A', '10D'}` or so.

Comment: @Yvon - Woah I totally forgot about hexadecimal.  Good catch!

Comment: @Erty - Do you require any more assistance?  Did this help?

Comment: @Erty - Better late than never. Thanks for the accept.