# MatLab operator overloading

Tags: function, matlab, object, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do properties work in Object Oriented MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209005/how-do-properties-work-in-object-oriented-matlab)

I have been using MatLab for quite some time but started using OOP just recently.

I have a class that is a simple linked list (it can be anything really). A few methods are declared in the class. Is it possible for the methods to modify the instance from which those are called?

`instance.plotData()` cannot modify any properties of the instance .

I have to return the instance for the function to actually have some effect on the instance itself:

```
instance = instance.plotData();
```

This seems really cumbersome. Is there a better way of achieving the task?

Addition:

```
classdef handleTest < handle

  properties
      number
  end

  methods
      function addNode(this)
          a = length(this);
          this(a+1) = handleTest;
      end
  end
end
```

If i call:

```
x = handleTest
x.addNode()
```

then `x` has still only one node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to derive from the `handle` class, i.e. use something like

```
classdef YourClass < handle
    function plotData(obj)
        ... modify the obj here ...
    end
end
```

However, this also has implications, if you copy the instance, i.e. if you do an

```
a = YourClass(...);
b = a;
```

then `b` is an **alias** for `a` and whenever you change `a`, you also modify `b` and vice
versa (meaning the data is only stored once in the background).

There is the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfylwk-1.html) for handle classes and the difference to value classes.

Comment: Thanks, Mehrwolf. Is it possible to add instances of class to an already defined instance that is controlled with such a handle? For example, I have a "node" class. n(1) = node(); is the initialization line of the class instance. I would like to add more nodes to the vector -- a function would then execute the following command: n(2) = node(); and then modify the parameters of the node. The Handle version does not seem to work. Am I misrepresenting the handle operator? Thanks, SunnyBuy

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY: Could you ask this as a new question and post a short code example of your `node`? I think, I do not get completely, what you try to do.

Comment: let me edit the question

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY: Ok, no I get the point. I would not try to add the handle to itself (inside the class) but instead create a vector of `handleTest`, which is stored somewhere in your calling program. If you want to wrap this vector, you could create another class e.g. `handleList`. This class has an `addNode()` that adds an instance of `handleTest` to the internal vector.