# Side effects of calling a MATLAB class instance don't persist

Tags: matlab, oop, matlab-class

If I make the following toy class in MATLAB:

```
classdef testIt
    properties
        a
        b
        c
    end
    methods
        function obj = testIt
            obj.a = 1;
            obj.b = 2;
        end

        function obj = set.a(obj,a)
            obj.a = a;
        end

        function obj = set.b(obj,b)
            obj.b = b;
        end

        function obj = addup(obj)
            obj.c = obj.a + obj.b;
        end
    end
end
```

and then instantiate and call the `addup` method:

```
>> aTest = testIt

Properties:
a: 1
b: 2
c: []

>> aTest.addup

Properties:
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3

>> aTest

Properties:
a: 1
b: 2
c: []
```

The property `c` has not been created. Instead, I need to use the syntax:

```
>> aTest = aTest.addup

>> aTest

Properties:
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is necessary?

Comment: kinda duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209005/how-do-properties-work-in-object-oriented-matlab), but @Jonas' answer is much nicer than the answers there :o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matlab supports two types of classes: **handle classes**, and **value classes**.

**Value classes** operate similar to structures and other Matlab variables, in that they are passed by value. Thus, if you want to modify an instance of a value class within a function, you need to return and overwrite the instance in the calling workspace.

**Handle classes**, on the other hand, are passed by reference. If you change the value of a property anywhere, the class is updated in all workspaces. For example, you can have a reference to the object in the base workspace, and one inside a GUI, and if you modify one, the other changes its value accordingly.

If you change your code to `classdef testIt < handle`, the objects will behave exactly the way you expect.

Also: [Have a look at the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

add to the class definition:

```
classdef testIt < handle
```